# cryptographic functions for 4kB of memory

Tags: c

I am trying to create a checksum for one page of memory. Can anyone suggest a checksum function which is fast and accurate. Surprisingly, I am finding it difficult to find on google. I need to write the function in C.

Thanks

Comment: howabout `md5sum`, `sha1sum`, `sha224sum`, `sha256sum`, `sha384sum` & `sha512sum`?

Comment: _accurate_ is not a very apt word for a checksum function.

Comment: Do you need the hash to be cryptography-quality, or just to have a low collision rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try md5 (http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) which is most commonly used or SHA-1 (http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) which is considered better than md5

Comment: Since the question title includes "cryptographic" - one should be cautious about using SHA-1 in new cryptographic applications, and should not use MD-5 in new cryptographic applications unless some unpleasant constraint necessitates it, and you can effectively analyse the consequences of MD5's known weaknesses and expected additional weaknesses in the fairly near future. Use one of the SHA-2 hashes unless there's a solid reason not to, and where possible build protocols that can smoothly switch to new hash functions in future.

Answer (score 0):

[MurmurHash3](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) is *very* fast and it has a relatively low collision rate. That said, it's not suitable for the production of cryptography-quality hashes, due to its simplicity.